# How to execute an exe file from AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have written a lambda function that executes another exe file named abc.exe.

Now I have created a zip of lambda function and uploaded it to aws. I am not sure **where to put my "abc.exe"**

I tried putting it in the same zip but I get below error:

> exec: "abc": executable file not found in $PATH:

Here is my lambda function code:

```
func HandleLambdaEvent(request Request) (Response, error) {

    fmt.Println("Input", request.Input)
    fmt.Println("Output", request.Output)

    cmd := exec.Command("abc", "-v", "--lambda", request.Input, "--out", request.Output)
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
        return Response{Message: fmt.Sprintf(stderr.String())}, nil
    }
    fmt.Println("Result: " + out.String())

    return Response{Message: fmt.Sprintf(" %s and %s are input and output", request.Input, request.Output)}, nil
}
```

**Update:**

*Trial 1:*

I uploaded abc.exe to s3 then in my HandleLambdaEvent function I am downloading it to tmp/ folder. And next when i try to access it after successful download, it shows below error:

> fork/exec /tmp/abc: no such file or directory:

Code to download abc.exe :

```
file, err2 := os.Create("tmp/abc.exe")
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to create file %q, %v", err2)
    }

    defer file.Close()


    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(region)},
    )

    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

    numBytes, err2 := downloader.Download(file,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String("abc.exe"),
        })
    if err2 != nil {
        fmt.Println("Unable to download item %q, %v", fileName, err2)
    }

    fmt.Println("Downloaded", file.Name(), numBytes, "bytes")
    file.Close()
```

Comment: I know next to nothing about Lambda, but are you sure you even _can_ execute an external binary? That seems counter-intuitive to me, like it violates the point of Lambda.

Comment: What sort of file is the `.exe` file? Is it a Windows app?

Comment: @Flimzy i am not sure either. It's trial and error for me as well. But to check whether lambda can execute binary, firstly I need a way to access it from lambda :)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It's golang executable program file.

Comment: I wonder if you can just use GO directly? [Announcing Go Support for AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-go-support-for-aws-lambda/) and [Building Lambda Functions with Go - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/go-programming-model.html)

Comment: I doubt that you are going in the correct direction, overall, but the immediate problem is that `.exe` is never implied in Linux.  The full filename, e.g. `exec.Command("abc.exe", ...` would be required.

Answer (score 3):

> are you sure you even can execute an external binary? That seems counter-intuitive to me, like it violates the point of Lambda

Perfectly acceptable. Have a look at [Running Arbitrary Executables in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda) on the AWS Compute Blog.

> I am not sure where to put my "abc.exe"

To run executables on Lambda *package them in the ZIP file you upload*. Then do something like

```
exec.Command(path.Join(os.GetEnv("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"), "abc.exe"))
```

> What sort of file is the .exe file? Is it a Windows app?

You won't be able to run Windows apps on Lambda. The linked blog post says: *If you compile your own binaries, ensure that they’re either statically linked or built for the matching version of Amazon Linux*

Comment: Environment Variables Available to Lambda Functions
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-environment-variables.html

Comment: How would you run the executable with commandline arguments? I am doing a similar thing in python, and am able to run the executable via `subprocess.Popen(args)` where args = "./abc.exe". Would I just add another element to the list of args?